# Scala 3 compiletime: value from type

Tags: scala, scala-3, scala-compiletime

I want to initialize a `val` with the value of a type parameter:

```
import scala.compiletime.constValue

trait Foo[N <: Int]:
  val m:Int=constValue[N]


val two = new Foo[2]{}.m
```

I get an error:

```
-- Error: ---------------------------------------------------------------
5 |  val m:Int=constValue[N]
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |            not a constant type: Foo.this.N; cannot take constValue
```

**How do I tell it to calculate `m` only after `N` is known?**

(Well, in fact, I want something a bit more complex:

```
trait Foo[N <: Int]:
  transparent inline def something[N]:Int = ??? // constValue[N] inside
  val m:Int=something[N]
```

but it fails on `constValue[N]`)

Answer (score 5):

`N` is known (should) when you are creating this trait. So you could pass it in a constructor argument of a `trait`

```
trait Foo[N <: Int](using N: ValueOf[N]):
  val m: Int = N.value
```

`ValueOf[N]` would be then provided when you instantiate the value

```
object Bar extends Foo[5]

println(Bar.m)
```

If you defer it further, you'd have to pass `ValueOf[N]` up till then place when it is known

```
def create[N <: Int : ValueOf]: Foo[N] =
  new Foo[N] {}

println(create[4].m)
```

`constValue[N]` would work if N was known e.g. if it was defined as

```
type N = 5
```

or if it was used inside an `inline` method which known the type of `N <: Int` passed into it

```
inline def something[N <: Int]: Int = scala.compiletime.constValue[N]

println(something[3])
```

In your second example you have two `N` defined, it would partially work if you did

```
trait Foo[N <: Int]:
  inline def something: Int = scala.compiletime.constValue[N]

println(new Foo[2]{}.something)
```

partially because `something` knows `N` when called from outside in the context where the exact type is known. Within `Foo` this is not true, so

```
  val m: Int = something
```

will always fail.